# Android Service to send email, code error

Tags: java, android, access-modifiers

I am developing a service to get current sim card value and detect whether sim card changed, if so i would like to implement JavaMail API in my service, which mean my service is able to send email.

Below is my code, code error in MyService.java

In row

```
public class GMailAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

showing error

```
illegal modifier for the local class GMailAsync; only abstract or final is permitted
```

Could someone guide me on this ? I want to enable my service to send email without user interact.

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {  

    String storedSimSerial;
    String currentSimSerial;

    @Override  
    public void onCreate() {  
        super.onCreate();    
    }  

    @Override  
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        TelephonyManager telephoneMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        storedSimSerial = telephoneMgr.getSimSerialNumber();
        Log.e("SimSerial::",storedSimSerial);

        TelephonyManager tmMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        currentSimSerial = tmMgr.getSimSerialNumber();
        Log.e("Current Sim Serial::",currentSimSerial);

        if(currentSimSerial.equals(storedSimSerial))
        {
            Log.e("Sim Status","Sim no changed !!!");
        }             
        else
            Log.e("Sim Status","Sim changed !!!");

        public class GMailAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String mail_body = "Sim serial number is "+currentSimSerial;
                String subject = "Your Sim has changed!!!";         
                GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("testing123@gmail.com", "testing");
                try {
                    sender.sendMail(subject, mail_body + "\nTGenerated Email",
                            "testing123@gmail.com",null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Log.d("Mail","Sent");
            }
        }

        return Service.START_STICKY;  
    }  

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override  
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {  
        return null;  
    }  
}
```

**GMailSender.java**

```
import javax.activation.DataHandler;   
import javax.activation.DataSource;   
import javax.mail.Message;   
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   
import javax.mail.Session;   
import javax.mail.Transport;   
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.OutputStream;   
import java.security.Security;   
import java.util.Properties;   

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   

    static {   
        Security.addProvider(new com.example.JSSEProvider());   
    }  

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {   
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
    }   

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
        Transport.send(message);   
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }   

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   
}
```

**JSSEProvider.java**

```
public class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: learn java first ... you trying define public class in method body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you are creating your `AsyncTask` inside the `onStartCommand` method. If you say it is public, then it's not a local variable.

Comment: It says that only abstract and final is permitted. ?

Comment: Why don't you create your `Asynctask` somewhere else in the code of your class and not in a method? If you want to call this task from your onStartCommand, you can then add new `GmailAsync().execute(params);` . Unless it's impossible in a Service, but I don't think so.

Comment: It says that because it is not possible to define a public class in a method. It can be final, because then it becomes a regular variable that you will never use outside of this method, eg a local variable. About the abstract modifier, I can't say why it is allowed here, it seems odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

Method-local classes can't be public. Remove public. Eclipse error message isn't precise. You can read about inner classes [here](http://inheritingjava.blogspot.ru/2011/02/chapter-53-method-local-inner-classes.html).

And I cant find a place where your trying to use this class. I think you declared it in wrong place.